# AWS Best practice - When external ip address on stop/start

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip-address

Here's what's bothering me. Is there a better way than sending emails to devs that the ip address for their dev server has changed after the instance is stopped and started?

I was thinking of a single small instance that has an elastic ip which the devs can log in using terminal, and ssh again to the internal ip address of the dev server. Is that effective?

Does it mean that the devs need to be informed of the change every time?

Comment: Just a side note... You can mail aws support to increase the limit of elastic ips... if you are not using elastic ips just because of limit of 5.

Comment: @Satyajeet To be honest, I don't want to use elastic ips on a dev server. I feel I am wasting precious ip address for just a dev server.

Comment: You are absolutely right... But i think primary purpose of elastic ip is to serve a machine which wants to be live forever....and i think dev server's life is closely related to production server...just an opinion...:)

Comment: And make the lives of the devs easier. Man, devops has some meta on it or at least, empathy should be part of being in a devops team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you are saying "there's a new public dns for the server"? -thanks for the comment, that's clearer what you mean!  It's the aws domain name in the format "ec2-54-222-213-143.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" you are referring to

You are asking how can these name/address changes be managed?

Generally speaking for fixing these kinds of problems there are a couple of things to be aware of

Firstly, if it is the public ip address that is changing instead of an ephemeral public ip address use an elastic ip.  This will stay the same and can be transferred from an old instance to a new instance.  Please read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html about the differences between "Elastic IP" and normal public IP addresses on AWS

Secondly, if you are concerned about maintenance of the dns records that map the ip addresses to the domain names then it is possible to automate the updates to aws route53.  I have used the aws cli command "route53 change-resource-record-sets" for this and also CloudFormation

Automating events to occur on instance start up does take a little research of the available APIs and hooks for example see this answer with a simple use of cloud-init [Using cloud-init user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819836/using-cloud-init-user-data)

Comment: yeah, sorry about the new public dns name. It's just the label in the aws console so that's what I have typed in. So everytime the instance needs to be stopped and started, the devs need to be informed about the change. Hmmm... how about ssh and ssh inside it? Is it a bit complex?

Comment: Ok, the cloud-init user data script does have potential. I could imagine having it to send an email to devs alerting them of the change that happened. Is that plausible?

Comment: 1 Corinthians 10:23, http://www.slideshare.net/dev2ops/with-selfservice-operations-the-cloud-is-just-expensive-hosting-20-a-devops-story